# Remove radio button and sibling text and <br> tag

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a .net shopping cart generating a radio button list.  I need some jquery to move shipping options that the owner doesn't want to use.  The code generated is

`<input type="radio" name="ShippingMethodID" id="ShippingMethodID9" value="68|Priority Mail Express International|59.22|0.00">&nbsp;Priority Mail Express International $59.22 (USD) <br>`

Unfortunately each shipping option has the same ID (which I know is a huge problem).  I need help selecting the radio button, text and `<br>` tag and removing them from the DOM. Can someone help remove the 3 items?

The selector that seems to work for the radio button is:
`$("input[type=radio][value^=68]")` but I'm unable to get the rest of the text and `<br>` tag.

***Unfortunately I can't alter the HTML that the shopping cart generates. I'm stuck with the markup.***

Comment: I have no control of the backend. Not ignorant thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in span then try code below

```
var input = $('input[type="radio"][value^=68]');
var text = input.next('span').text('');
var br = input.next().next('br').remove();
input.remove();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't alter the HTML that the shopping cart generates. I'm stuck with the markup as referenced in my question.

Comment: what is a parent tag of input?

Answer (score -1):

You can hide them with jQuery.

[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

something like:

```
$("radio #idname").hide(0);
```

If they all have the same id then you'll have to do a nest. So something like:

```
$("#container .div1 .div2 radio").hide(0);
```

Comment: I would need to select based on the value as I mentioned, which is working. I need help removing the text and `br` tag

Comment: One method is to not use br tags and using something a bit more semantically correct

Comment: folks, I'm stuck with the HTML as is. I'd ideally like to fix it that way